# How do I count the number of distinct values of a column based on another column criterion?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
owner     unit_id   detail
abc123    002NH034  94847DT
abc123    002NH034  94868DT
abc123    002NH034  94889DT
abc123    112NH035  94899DT
abc123    112NH036
abc123    112NH037
```

I'm trying to roll up to the level of the first column, while counting the number of distinct values in the second column that have a value in the third column. So expected output would be:

```
abc123  2
```

I've tried a mix of `sum`, `is.na`, and a few other dplyr functions but am a little stuck. I've tried a variation of the following with random other functions but keep getting sums of all the rows.

```
df %>%  group_by(owner) %>% summarise(unit_ids_with_detail = sum(!is.na(detail))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(detail)) %>%  group_by(owner) %>% 
summarise(unit_ids_with_detail = n_distinct(unit_id))
```

Remove NAs from third column, group by first column, count distinct values on second column. This will drop owners that have only NAs on the third column, though

Comment: Nice, +1. You could also use `tidyr::drop_na(detail)` as a slight shortcut for `dplyr::filter(!is.na(detail))`.

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned that I can't do filtering, since I'm already doing `n_distinct(unit_id)` to get the number of all unit_ids

Answer (score 0):

If we want the distinct elements, use `n_distinct` - Grouped by 'owner', use `n_distinct` on the 'unit_id' and specify `na.rm = TRUE` to remove the `NA` elements

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
   group_by(owner) %>% 
   summarise(unit_ids_with_detail = n_distinct(detail, na.rm = TRUE))
```